# React Markdown not render properly in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, markdown, react-markdown

I am creating dev.to clone for react js practice when

trying to render markdown in react-markdown it doesn't render properly,

here it is:

#### **Post.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import SyntexHighlight from '../../components/SyntexHighlight';


const Post = ({ post }: any) => {


  return (
    <main className="h-full bg-white rounded-md border">
      <header>
        .........
      </header>
      <div
        className=" leading-8 marker:text-black max-w-2xl mx-auto py-6 prose
          prose-lg prose-p:block prose-li:py-[0.5] prose-li:my-0 prose-a:text-blue-600
         hover:prose-a:text-blue-500 prose-code:text-sm prose-code:bg-gray-200 
          prose-code:p-1 prose-code:rounded prose-img:mx-auto       "
      >
        <ReactMarkdown components={SyntexHighlight}>{post.body}</ReactMarkdown>
      </div>

      <section className="border-t-2 px-8 py-4">
        ........
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

#### SyntexHighlight.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Prism } from 'react-syntax-highlighter';
import { oneDark } from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/cjs/styles/prism';

const SyntexHighlight = {
  code({ node, inline, className, ...props }: any) {
    const match = /language-(\w+)/.exec(className || '');
    return !inline && match ? (
      <Prism style={oneDark} language={match[1]} PreTag="div" className="codeStyle" {...props} />
    ) : (
      <code className={className} {...props} />
    );
  },
};

export default SyntexHighlight;
```

It doesn't render properly

[markdown render problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoYdM.png)

[markdown render problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLvPy.png)

[markdown render problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqMn9.png)

I tried  "json2md" package after getting JSON string form node server still not working
when i try "json2md" data  to separate variable

[data variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMS41.png)

```
<div
        className=" leading-8 marker:text-black max-w-2xl mx-auto py-6 prose
          prose-lg prose-p:block prose-li:py-[0.5] prose-li:my-0 prose-a:text-blue-600
         hover:prose-a:text-blue-500 prose-code:text-sm prose-code:bg-gray-200 
          prose-code:p-1 prose-code:rounded prose-img:mx-auto       "
      >
        <ReactMarkdown components={SyntexHighlight}>{MarkdownFile}</ReactMarkdown>
      </div>
```

Now its working properly

[it's working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOVyB.png)

[it's working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGPzx.png)

[it's working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka5R7.png)

i don't know what is the problem ???